# Basic sequence convergence proof check

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let a,b, $c \in \mathbb R$. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges to a and that $\{b_n\}$ converges to b. By definition prove that the sequence $\{\pi a_n - 9cb_n\}$ converges.

My solution: \

CASE 1:

If c = 0, then $\{ c9b_n \} = \{0,0,\cdots, 0\} \Rightarrow 0 = 09b$. But this still converges for $\{ \pi a_n \} \Rightarrow \pi a$

$\exists a \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{\pi}$

Suppose $n > N$, then

$|\pi a_n - \pi a| = |\pi (a_n - a)| < \pi \frac{\epsilon}{ \pi} = \epsilon$

Case 2:

Assuming $c \neq 0$

(1) $\exists a \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_1$, then $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi}$

(2) $\exists b \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_2$, then $|b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{18|c|}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N = max$(N_1, N_2) > 0$

Suppose $n > N$, then

$$|\pi a_n -c9b_n - (\pi a - 9bc)|

$$= \pi \frac{\epsilon}{2 \pi } + 9|c| \frac{\epsilon}{18 |c|}$$

$$= \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$ As required

Never worked with this type of proof before. Could someone verify, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very well constructed proof, with some minor glitches (I could just edit them out, but it's good that you see them:

1. What about if $c=0$? Then $\frac{\epsilon}{18|c|}$ is not a well defined term...
2. In the second row, instead of $|\pi(a_n)-a|$, you should have $|\pi(a_n-a)|$
3. In the second to last row, you should instead of $9c\frac{\epsilon}{18|c|}$ have $9|c|\frac{\epsilon}{18|c|}$

Other than that, yes, your proof is very good. It clearly shows that the sequence converges to $\pi a- 9cb$

---

**Edit**:

Your proof is now complete. The only thing left is you have to move the "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary" to the beginning of the proof.

Just for an alternative (slightly shorter) version, you could also tackle the $c=0$ situation in this way:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

(1) $\exists a \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_1$, then $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi}$

(2) If $c\neq 0$, then $\exists b \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_2$, then $|b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{18|c|}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose $N = \max(N_1, N_2) > 0$

Suppose $n > N$, then

$$|\pi a_n -c9b_n - (\pi a - 9bc)| = |\pi (a_n - a) + 9c(b - b_n)|$$

$$\leq |\pi (a_n - a)| + |9c(b_n - b)| \text{ by triangle inequality}$$

- We know that $|\pi (a_n - a)| \leq \pi \frac{\epsilon}{2 \pi }\leq \frac\epsilon2$
- if $c=0$, then $|9c(b_n-b)| = 0\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and if $c\neq 0 $, then $|9c(b_n-b)|\leq 9|c| \frac{\epsilon}{18 |c|}=\frac\epsilon2$. In both cases, $|9c(b_n-b)|\leq \frac\epsilon2$.

Therefore, $$|\pi (a_n - a)| + |9c(b_n - b)|\leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$ as required

Comment: XD ! I just saw them too. Thank you !

Comment: @user349557 Found one more problem (see the first point of my answer now after the edit)

Comment: Can I say at the top assuming $c \neq 0$?

Comment: @user349557 Not really, since you have to prove convergence for all values of $c$. The safest bet is to tackle the $c=0$ possibility separately.

Comment: If c = 0, then $\{ c9b_n \} = \{0,0,\cdots, 0\} \Rightarrow 0 = 09b$. I'm not sure. With c = 0 it would just be $\{\pi a_n\} = \pi a - 0$

Comment: @user349557 Exactly. It's actually even easier if $c=0$. But in order for your proof to be complete, you have to explain that. You can't just divide by a number that could be zero in the middle of your proof.

Comment: Hmm. Can I do a seperate part where I just prove $\{\pi a_n\}$ converges, explaining how $\{c9 b_n\}$ is zero? Then for the rest I just put now assuming $c \neq 0$ ?

Comment: @user349557 Exactly. You just have to add a small part into your proof saying "If $c=0$, then the sequence becomes $\pi a_n$, and this converges because blablabla. From now on, I assume that $c\neq 0$".

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much =)

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question if you don't mind. If I were to split this into cases will I have to restate the WTS again? Because for case1 I would get $< \epsilon/2$, but by definition shouldn't it just be $\epsilon $?

Comment: @user349557 In that case, yes. To make the proof complete, you have to re-do it for $c=0$.

Comment: @user349557 Looks good! See my edit.

Comment: Thx for all the help.